# Plotting direction field in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot direction field for a simple equation:

```
y'  = 3 − 2y
```

I have found similar Matlab problem [here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~efendiev/math442_spring04/matlabode.pdf) (1.3). But I do not know how to rewrite it to python. My last try is:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nx, ny = .3, .3
x = np.arange(-3, 3, nx)
y = np.arange(-2, 2, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

dy = X + np.sin(Y)
dx = np.ones((10,10))

plot2 = plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X, Y, dx, dy, 
           color='Teal', 
           headlength=7)

plt.title('Quiver Plot, Single Colour')
plt.show(plot2)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
builtins.ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (280,)
```

I though it will be very simple, but after few hours of searching how to plot a simple direction field, I am quite depressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dx` and `dy` must be of the same shape as `X` and `Y`.

Currently, you have a shape of `(14, 20)` for `X`, `Y` and `dy`, but `(10,10)` for `dx`.

If you change the line defining `dx` to:

```
dx = np.ones(dy.shape)
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the [streamlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) of the filed to give a nice impression of the flow, and colour the curves according to some property of the field (dy in this case). Look at the following example:

```
nx, ny = .3, .3
x = np.arange(-3, 3, nx)
y = np.arange(-2, 2, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
dy = X + np.sin(Y)
dx = np.ones(dy.shape)

color = dy
lw = 1
plt.streamplot(X,Y,dx, dy, color=color, density=1., cmap='jet', arrowsize=1)
```

which produces:

[image]